# how to catch POST and GET arrays from a PHP script called by dygraph

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post, graphics

I have a dygraph that displays data from a database. The data is provided by a PHP script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function drawChart(){
    var data = "get_data.php";
    var g = new Dygraph(
       document.getElementById("chart"),
       data,
       {
          legend: 'always',
          ylabel: 'y label',
          connectSeparatedPoints: true
       } // options
    );
}    

drawChart();
</script>
```

I would like to select a custom time period using two input boxes by a post or get method and parse their values in the php script "get_data.php", but the $_POST and $_GET arrays are not available in "get_data.php" called by JavaScript of dygraph.

Comment: did you try to pass your vars via the url ? : var data = "get_data.php?value1=1&value2=2";

Comment: yes, thats the correct answer: I've replaced
    var data = "get_data.php";
with
  <?php echo "var data = \"get_data.php?startdate=".$_GET['startdate']."&enddate=".$_GET['enddate']."\";";?>  
and it does the trick; I wonder how can we parse POST if we want to hide the parameters?